# How to set up limited, web-only access for unmanaged devices BUT grant saving/printing for external shared files?

Tags: sharepoint-online, access, conditional

Community,

I need some help with different access controls for unmanaged devices in my company.
Users inside the company having limited, web-only access to SPO sites and content, if they are using unmanaged devices.
External shared files will be opened on unmanaged devices outside the company. They should be able to print and download the files.

The limitation of web-only access on unmanaged devices is blocking saving/printing of external shared content.

How could I solve this problem?

Thanks for your help,
Simon

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think that's possible.

The point of access control on unmanaged devices is to remove the ability to **download**, **print**, or **sync** files for security consideration. It is not supported to exclude only external shared contents from the policy.
(See the third *Note* in Section “*Limit access*” via this [document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/control-access-from-unmanaged-devices#limit-access).)

As a workaround, you can adjust limit access settings on site level. For example, [use PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/control-access-from-unmanaged-devices#advanced-configurations) to change the value of property `LimitedAccessFileType`.
Or [configure exclusion policy for specific users](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/governance/conditional-access-exclusion) via Azure AD.